# Refactor rename so it doesn't look in external libraries

Tags: pycharm, refactoring

When I use `Refactor` `>` `Rename` in PyCharm, it takes a really long time (about 10 seconds), and it looks inside all of my external libraries (everything installed with pip), even when I'm just renaming one local variable in a < 100 line script. Also, it tries to rename variables from those files too, so I have to manually pick through them and exclude them from the refactor. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Have your external libraries been included (check in `Settings -> Project -> Project Structure`) to content root?

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk Yes, my virtualenv is a subdirectory of my current content root. Just realizing that, I marked my virtualenv directory as "excluded" and now refactoring works the way I want it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All files inside what PyCharm calls "Content Root" (generally the files inside your main project directory) are searched when you use refactor. You can choose to exclude a given folder in `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Project` `>` `Project Structure` as show in the screenshot.

[image]

An alternative is using `Replace in Files` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd> and defining a custom [Scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/scope.html).